# Want to prove $Aut(A_{n})\simeq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ where $A_{n}$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-groups, free-abelian-group

I'm trying to prove that $Aut(A_{n}) \simeq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$, where $A_{n}$ is a free abelian group of finite rank $n$.

I have already available to me the result that $A_{n} \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{n}$, so essentially what I have to prove is that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}^{n}) \simeq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.

To that effect, I considered $E = \{e_{1}, e_{2}, \cdots, e_{n}\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^{n} \simeq A_{n}$, where $\forall i$, $e_{i}$ is of the form $(0, 0, \cdots, 0, 1, 0, \cdots, 0)$ (all entries from $1$ to $i-1$ are $0$, the $i$th entry is $1$, and all entries from $i+1$ to $n$ are $0$.

Then, I let $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}^{n} \to \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ be the automorphism where $\varphi: e_{i} \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^{n}m_{ij}e_{j}$. (So, essentially, the $m_{ij}$ are "coordinates" of each $e_{i}$ in terms of the basis elements $e_{j}$).

Then, I thought about setting up a map $\mu: \varphi \mapsto M_{\varphi}$ where $M_{\varphi}$ would be an $n\times n$ matrix with integer entries $m_{ij}$.

Before I can even show that this map $\mu$ is an isomorphism, however, I must first show that it is a homomorphism.

So, to that effect, I thought I'd set up another automorphism $\psi: \mathbb{Z}^{n} \to \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ where $\psi: e_{i} \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{ij}e_{j}$. Then, I'd need to show that $\mu(\varphi \circ \psi) = \mu(\varphi(\psi(e_{i}))) = M_{\varphi}M_{\psi}$.

I'm not even sure that I defined $\psi$ correctly, and then when I tried to actually expand $\mu(\varphi \circ \psi)$ hoping I could get the matrices to pop out, I got as far as the following:

$\mu(\varphi \circ \psi) = \mu(\varphi(\psi(e_{i}))) = \mu(\varphi(k_{i1}e_{1} + k_{i2}e_{2} + \cdots + k_{ii}e_{i}+\cdots + k_{in}e_{n}) = \mu(\varphi(k_{i1}e_{1})+ \varphi(k_{i2}e_{2}) + \cdots + \varphi(k_{ii}e_{i})+ \cdots + \varphi (k_{in}e_{n})) = \mu\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{i1}m_{ij}e_{j} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} k_{i2}m_{ij}e_{j} + \cdots + \sum_{j=1}^{n} k_{ii}m_{ij}e_{j} + \cdots + \sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{in}m_{ij}e_{j}\right) = \mu \left(\left[k_{i1}m_{i1}e_{1} + k_{i1}m_{i2}e_{2} + \cdots + k_{i1}m_{ii}e_{i} + \cdots + k_{i1}m_{in}e_{n} \right] + \left[k_{i2}m_{i1}e_{1} + k_{i2}m_{i2}e_{2} + \cdots + k_{i2}m_{ii}e_{i} + \cdots + k_{i2}m_{in}e_{n} \right] + \cdots + \left[k_{in}m_{i1}e_{1} + k_{in}m_{i2}e_{2} + \cdots + k_{in}m_{ii}e_{i} + \cdots + k_{in}m_{in}e_{n} \right]  \right)$

Then, I figure I'd need to collect terms in such a way as to, once applying $\mu$, I would obtain $M_{\varphi}M_{\psi} = \begin{pmatrix} m_{11} & m_{12}  & \cdots & m_{1n} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} & \cdots & m_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots&  & \vdots \\ m_{n1} & m_{n2} & \cdots & m_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12}  & \cdots & k_{1n} \\ k_{21} & k_{22} & \cdots & k_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots&  & \vdots \\ k_{n1} & k_{n2} & \cdots & k_{nn}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{1i}k_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{1i}k_{i2} & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{1i}k_{in} \\\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{2i}k_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{2i}k_{i2} & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{2i}k_{in} \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{ni}k_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{ni}k_{i2} & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{ni}k_{in}   \end{pmatrix}$.

With what I've done so far is this even going to happen?

For the $\mu(\varphi(k_{i1}e_{1})+ \varphi(k_{i2}e_{2}) + \cdots + \varphi(k_{ii}e_{i})+ \cdots + \varphi (k_{in}e_{n})) = \mu\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{i1}m_{ij}e_{j} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} k_{i2}m_{ij}e_{j} + \cdots + \sum_{j=1}^{n} k_{ii}m_{ij}e_{j} + \cdots + \sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{in}m_{ij}e_{j}\right)$

part, can I pull the $k_{i1}, k_{i2}$, etc. out of the $\sum$'s and hence out of the $\varphi$'s?

In any case, if someone could please help me show that this map $\mu$ is a homomorphism, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you! I'm getting bogged down in these summations, and I'm figuring there has to be an easier way to show this.

Comment: If you know $(AB)v=A(Bv)$ for square matrices $A,B$ and vectors $v$, you could instead define a map ${\rm GL}(n,\Bbb Z)\to {\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z^n)$, which is easier to verify is a homomorphism, then verify injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: It's cleaner to first show that the endomorphism ring of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ (because here you can appeal to the universal property of $\mathbb{Z}^n$); then the automorphism group is just the group of units of the endomorphism ring. In general it's usually easier to compute the endomorphism ring of an abelian group in order to compute its automorphism group. A somewhat tricky example is computing the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm not allowed to appeal to ring theory at all here.

Comment: @arctictern what would such a map be? Basically just the reverse of the one I defiined in my question?

Comment: In other words, how to interpret a matrix as a function that sends vectors to vectors? You already know how: matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there's an easier way.

It may serve you well to pick up a linear algebra textbook and see how this is done for matrix-representations of linear maps on $\Bbb F^n$.  Then again, there are some textbooks that also get bogged down in summations, so that depends on the textbook.

In any case, the quicker approach is as follows: to show that $\mu$ is a homomorphism, it suffices to note that
$$
\mu(\varphi)v = \varphi(v)
$$
for any $\varphi \in GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ and $v \in \Bbb Z^n$.  Here, $\mu(\varphi)v$ denotes matrix multiplication, whereas $\varphi(v)$ is an application.  With that, we can deduce that for any $v \in \Bbb Z^n$,
$$
\mu(\varphi \circ \psi)v = (\varphi \circ \psi)(v) = 
\varphi(\psi(v)) = \mu(\varphi)\psi(v) = \mu(\varphi)\mu(\psi)v
$$
from which we may conclude that $\mu(\varphi \circ \psi) = \mu(\varphi)\mu(\psi)$, as desired.

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look at this in the morning, but your moniker is making me hungry.

Comment: I like to think of it as more of an omniker.  Be sure to take a look though; from what I"ve seen in the movies, you have trouble with your memory.

Comment: actually, do you mean something different by $\phi$ and $\varphi$ here? My intention in my question was not to make $\varphi$ an element of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$. Also, how do you know that $\mu(\phi)v = \phi(v)$, that's not what we're trying to prove?

Comment: @JessyunBourne it's certainly *related* to what we're trying to prove.  However, the fact that your $\mu$ is an isomorphism makes no reference in itself to the fact that both of the groups in question have a natural action over the module $\Bbb Z^n$. Likewise, your proof does not exploit this additional structure.

Comment: not rings. And what's the deal with the $\phi$ vs $\varphi$'s?

Comment: Excuse me, I meant groups.  There was no difference between the $\phi$'s, I just forgot to change the first few to the fancy version.

Comment: Note: to show that $\mu(\varphi)v = \varphi(v)$, it suffices to show that
$$
\mu(\varphi)\left(\sum_i a_i e_i\right) = 
\varphi\left(\sum_i a_i e_i\right)
$$
which is fairly straightforward using a sensible definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: I posted an answer to this question that I asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129331/find-a-finite-generating-set-for-gln-mathbbz but after a point, I got stuck and am not sure how to finish it. Can you help me? The answer is community wiki so anyone can edit it.

Comment: I'm so incredibly stuck on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129331/find-a-finite-generating-set-for-gln-mathbbz. I don't understand how the hint and answer that were given to me are going to help me prove what I want. There aren't enough specific details in them to do me any good. Could you pleas help?