# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, automorphism-group

my professor said that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2) \cong GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. But I don't quite understand why.

An automorphism of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ can be represented as a matrix multiplication: $\phi \left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right) = M \cdot \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}ax+cy\\bx+dy\end{pmatrix}$.

But then why is $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2) \cong GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$? Considering $M = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$, there is no element $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $Mx = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, which means multiplication by $M$ is not bijective.

I have thought of an argument that shows $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2) \cong SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, but I'm not sure whether that's correct either.

Where is my error?

Comment: Your example is not invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$, is it?

Comment: $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is defined as the set of *invertible* 2x2 matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore your $M$ is not in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.  So $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ is indeed true. $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. matrices in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ have determinant $1$, while matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ can have determinant $1$ or $-1$ (maybe its a good excercise to proove that no other values alre possible?)

Comment: This seems to be a misunderstanding of notation: $GL_2 (\mathbb{Z})$ denotes the group of all matrices that are invertible over the integers, not that have integer coefficients and are invertible in some bigger ring. Such matrices must have determinant in $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}=\{\pm1\}$. Check your proof for where you might have missed the automorphism that is given by multiplying one generator by $1$ and one by $-1$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's it – I had the wrong definition of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z^n)\cong GL_n(\Bbb Z)$, what your professor said. This is proved here:

[Want to prove $Aut(A_{n})\simeq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ where $A_{n}$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126975/want-to-prove-auta-n-simeq-gln-mathbbz-where-a-n-is-a-free-abeli)

The general linear group over a commutative ring $R$ with $1$ is given by the $n\times n$-matrices $A\in M_n(R)$, which are invertible over $R$, so that $A^{-1}\in M_n(R)$. This is equivalent to the fact that $\det(A)$ is a unit in $R$. Hence
$$
GL_n(\Bbb Z)=\{A\in M_n(\Bbb Z)\mid \det(A)=\pm 1\}.
$$

Your matrix $M=2I$ is definitely not in $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$.