# Prove that Aut($\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$) $\cong$ $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, automorphism-group, general-linear-group

Prove that Aut($\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$) $\cong$ $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.

This is a HW problem for an Algebra course, hints/suggestions welcome.

I didn't find this problem on math.SE, however I did find a partial solution in the course notes of a different university, which gave me the general form of the argument.

My attempt is below. There are a couple details I think I don't understand fully, and to me the statements sound a bit fuzzy - I've indicated these with $\star \dots \star$.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\aut}{Aut}$
Recall that automorphisms are completely determined by the images of generators. Write an element $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ as a column vector $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} a \\ b \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and let $\varphi_M$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ given by $\varphi_M \left( \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \right)= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} a\\ b \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ and $\varphi_M \left( \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \right)= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} c\\ d \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ for some integers $a,b,c,d$. $\star$ Note that $\varphi_M$ therefore corresponds to left multiplication by the matrix $M := \left( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \right)$. $\star$

Since $\varphi_M$ is an automorphism, it has an inverse $\varphi_{M^{-1}}$ associated to a matrix $M^{-1}$ such that $MM^{-1}=I$. It follows that $\det M \det M^{-1} = (ad-bc)\det M^{-1} =1$, and therefore $\det M = \pm 1$, which implies that $M\in \operatorname{GL}_2 (\mathbb Z)$. Conversely, a matrix $N\in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ is invertible, so it corresponds to an automorphism $\varphi_N \in \aut(\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)$. Thus we have a bijection $\aut(\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)\to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$, $\star$ so to get an isomorphism it suffices to observe that composition of automorphisms corresponds to matrix multiplication. $\star$ Hence $\aut(\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)\cong \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z).$

Is this argument correct, and how can I fill in the details of the $\star$ sentences with a more precise statement?

**Edit:** I think it's also worth asking if there is a more streamlined approach to answering this question?

Comment: Yes your approach to check the claim is fine, not sure of what you expect by posting it here. The determinant part depends on how you define $GL_2$, it is a theorem that the two definitions are equivalent (integer matrices whose inverse is an integer matrix, and integer matrices whose determinant is a unit in the integers)

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126975/want-to-prove-auta-n-simeq-gln-mathbbz-where-a-n-is-a-free-abeli) for showing that ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z^n)\cong GL_n(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Thanks - this one slipped my search inquiries due to using the notation of free abelian group instead of $\mathbb Z^n$

Comment: I overlooked my [own answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122048/automorphisms-of-mathbbz2?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well :)