Understanding Multiplicative Group Structure On Hom$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}))$
Motivation. This post comes in direct response to the fact that $($Hom$(G,G'),+)$ inherits an (additive) group structure whenever $G, G'$ are abelian. In particular, I'm curious what properties one could derive with respect to semi-direct product and group actions noting these facts:

Given $H=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $K=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, then the collection of all semidirect products $H\rtimes_{\alpha} K$ is defined in direct correspondence with $\alpha\in\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{*})$.

Given a group action from $K$ on $H$ (as defined prior), then all group actions can be uniquely defined with respect to any $\alpha\in\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{*})$. (This statement could also be viewed as a more powerful generalization of the previous.)


Question. How could we employ the multiplicative/abelian group structure on $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{*})$ into (i) construcuing the collection of all semidirect products between two given finite cyclic groups, and (ii) what even is the structure of the Hom group in this context?
To maybe be a little more precise in my second question: Are there any rules which can be used to defined all homomorphisms? For instance, describing all homomorphisms in Hom$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ simply boils down to looking at order and how the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ will map. Since there is no guarantee that $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ will be cyclic, the question in the newly presented context becomes a little more complicated...and I'm curious if there are any facts I have just yet to come across?
I tried looking for answers to this question across the site as well other sources, but have yet to find anything satisfactory. Thank you for your time, all!

The image of $1$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ must be an element of order $d\mid n$ in $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times,$ and any such element gives a unique homomorphism.

It is a little confusing to refer to the group structure on $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^)$ as "additive structure", given that the structure you are inheriting comes from the group structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^$, which is a group under modular multiplication, not modular addition.

@ArturoMagidin When I use the term "additive structure", I really mean "abelian structure but with group operator inherited from the abelian group ($\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{*}$". (Generally, I view "addition" as the standard notation for a commutative group operator...if this makes any sense?)

I know what you mean. But $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ has two standard operations on it: addition and multiplication. The group operation on $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ is definitely mulitplication, so calling it "adddition", when there is an addition defined on its elements (though that addition is an operation in a set containing it) is confusing. It will become even worse if you start using $+$ as the symbol for this operation. Are you going to say that $m=5$, we will have "$2+3=1$"? Surely not. The operation already has a name, and the name you are using refers to a different operation.

It's an abelian group structure under pointwise multiplication. That's what it's called.

In general, if $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$ then $Z_{m_1m_2}^\times$ is isomorphic to $Z_{m_1}^\times\times Z_{m_2}^\times,$ so we ultimately want to find elements of the form $Z_{p^k}^{\times},$ with $p$ prime. When $p$ is odd m this 8s a cyclic group of order $p^{k-1}(p-1),$ and you'll need elements which have order a divisor of$n_1=\gcd(n,p^{k-1}(p-1),$ which are exactly the powers of elements $x^{p^{k-1}(p-1)/n_1}.$ For $p=2$ it will be a little more complicated, because $Z_{2^k}^\times$ is not cyclic when $k>2,$ and instead, $\mathbb Z_{2^k}^\times\cong Z_2\times Z_{2^{k-2}}$ for $k\geq 2.$

The structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^$ is completely determined by its prime factorization; it breaks up into a product of cyclic groups of orders $2^k$, or $(p-1)p^a$ with $p$ an odd prime, $a,k$ nonnegative integers. A map into $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^$ is completely determined by its value in each of these factors, so you you end up just having to worry about maps of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ into cyclic groups of those orders.

[Aside]: I don't see how the group structure on $G$ plays any role here.

@ThomasAndrews I see. The typo midway through your post are giving me a hard-time, though: "m this 8s a cyclic group"(?). I assume this is a typo? Or am I just not understanding?

@ArturoMagidin Got it! That makes sense, though I presume you meant "cyclic groups of orders $2^{k-1}$"?

It's a cyclic group of order a power of $2$. If $2^r$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides $m$, then you get a factor of the form $(\mathbb{Z}/2^m\mathbb{Z})^*$; this group is trivial if $r=1$, and is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/2^{r-2}\mathbb{Z})$ if $r\geq 2$. So you get factors that are cyclic of order "a power of $2$". Why would I write an arbitrary power of $2$ as $2^{k-1}$ instead of $2^k$? That's also why I write $(p-1)p^a$ and not $(p-1)p^{a-1}$.

Sorry, my iPad goes into numeric/symbol mode too easily, and I haven't gotten used to editing my comments to protect against it.

@ArturoMagidin Oh sorry, I see now. I read your post after having read Thomas', where he chose $k$ so that $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^{*}$, hence $2^{k-1}$ would be the order (according to Euler Totient map). That's good! Thank you.

@JAG131 Except it wouldn't, because the units modulo $2^k$ are not cyclic when $k\geq 3$.

@ArturoMagidin The order of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^{*}$ is not $2^{k-1}$?

@JAG131 The order is $2^{k-1}$, but you do not get a cyclic factor of order $2^{k-1}$.

As time goes on, the response I give here will be updated, so as to provide an increasingly more sufficient response to the question I had initially posed. Being how vague I was in my initial question, I feel it is only possible for me to provide a suitable response, which I provide upon having read the provided comments above.
The structure of this post is as follows: I start by discussing some fundamental facts which may (or may not) be obvious to the reader. For purposes of keeping the focus of the post fixated on latter statements, I provide only informal proofs, accompanied by links to more formal explanations found on MathSE. Upon having established the fundamental facts, I then will dive into some less obvious (though still kinda obvious) facts pertaining to the group structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. These properties will be very useful in describing the structure of Hom$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{*})$, as will be seen throughout the post. If you have any questions, remarks, or anything else, please comment them below.

Prerequisite Fact 0. Defining $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$.

We define the underlying set of this multiplicative group as being the collection of all units (i.e. elements with multiplicative inverse) $\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. This can equivalently be restated as $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}=$$\{[a]\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}:a\in\mathbb{Z},\ \text{gcd}(a,n)=1\}$.

- Notable about this group is that it inherits the largest (wrt set inclusion) possible underlying set contained $\subset\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ which allows for a well-defined multiplicative group to be constructed. This is because $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ contains every element which has multiplicative inverse (hence, any larger group must necessarily contain elements which lack a multiplicative inverse, contradicting the invertibility axiom of group).
- For those curious in developing further intuition or receiving greater exposure to this group, linked is a compilation of example multiplicative groups (sourced from Wikipedia).
Prerequisite Fact 1. Identifying every $\phi\in$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$

Let $\Sigma=\{[a]\in\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}:o([a])\text{ divides }n\}\triangleleft\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and consider the map $\phi_{\_}:\Sigma\to$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ defined so that $\phi_{x}(1)=x$. Then $\phi_{\_}$ denotes an isomorphism (where the Hom-set inherits group operator from $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$), hence provides a means of identifying all group homomorphisms between the two groups $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. (Proof of identification, but not isomorphism.)

- An important fact about homomorphisms $\phi\in$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ is that (i) $o(\phi(x))$ must divide $o(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and (ii) $\phi(x)=x\cdot\phi(1)$ (because of the cyclic structure on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$). Therefore, as a consequence of these two facts, it follows that all homomorphisms $\phi\in$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ are uniquely constructed according to $\phi(1)=\alpha$ where $\alpha\in\Sigma$. It's easy to confirm that $\Sigma$ denotes a well-defined (normal) subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. (Though if anybody would like for me to type it out explicitly, please comment.)
Prerequisite Fact 2. For $n\in\mathbb{N}^{>0},$ then $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}\cong$ Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$.
- The proof behind this claim is straight-forward once you keep in mind the fact that (i) automorphisms $\phi\in$ Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ are defined entirely according to their output of the $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ generator (i.e. the value of $\phi(1)$), and (ii) that therefore $\phi(1)={\alpha}$ corresponds to a well-defined automorphism if and only if $\alpha\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ (noting that isomorphisms map generators to generators). If we were to consider the map $\phi_{\_}:(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}\to$ Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ defined such that $\phi_a(1)=a$ ($a\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$), then $\phi_a\circ\phi_b=\phi_{ab}$ (since $\phi_a\circ\phi_b(1)=\phi_{a}(b)=ab=\phi_{ab}(1)$) for any $a,\ b\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. By (i) and (ii), we conclude that $g$ denotes a well-defined isomorphism, and so we're done.

Observation 1. Prime Factorization of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$.

Let $n=\prod_{j=1}^{k}p_j^{d_j}$ where $p_j\neq2$ for all $j\in\{1,...,k\}$. Then $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}\cong\prod_{j=1}^{k}$$(\mathbb{Z/}p_j^{d_j}\mathbb{Z})^{*}$.


Proof. We depart from Group Theory for the moment, favoring an approach which examines the statement from a Ring Theoretic perspective. Choose $m_1,\ m_2\in\mathbb{N}$ so that gcd$(m_1,m_2)=1$, and consider the canonical ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/m_1m_2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/m_1\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m_2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $phi$ defines a ring isomorphism (this is easy to check noting that ker$(\phi)=1$ as a consequence of coprimes, $|\mathbb{Z}/m_1m_2\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{Z}/m_1\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m_2\mathbb{Z}|=m_1m_2$, and confirming well-defined homomorphism). Since ring isomorphism maps units bijectively to units, indeed $\phi$ induces a (multiplicative) group isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/m_1m_2\mathbb{Z})^{*}\to(\mathbb{Z}/m_1\mathbb{Z})^{*}\times(\mathbb{Z}/m_2\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ noting that an element in $(\mathbb{Z}/m_1\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m_2\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ is a unit if and only if it is a unit component-wise (i.e. it is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/m_1\mathbb{Z})^{*}\times(\mathbb{Z}/m_2\mathbb{Z})^{*}$).

Observation 2. (Prime number $p\neq 2$) Cyclic Structure on $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^{*}$.

Choose prime $p\neq2$. Then $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ (where $k\in\mathbb{N}^{>0}$) denotes a cyclic group order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$.


Proof. The route is simple: We find elements of order and $p^{k-1}$ and order divisible by $(p-1)$ (resp.) in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. By fact that the group of interest is abelian, it follows order of the product of these two elements will be the least common multiple, i.e. $=(p-1)p^{k-1}$. To cut this proof short, the two elements of interest will be $[p+1],\ [r]\in(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ where $[r]$ denotes the generator of cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ The former will be of the larger order, and can quickly be checked using the binomial formula. The latter will have order divisible by $(p-1)$ since it'll have order of $(p-1)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. Since $|(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^{*}|=(p-1)p^{k-1}$ (according to Euler totient formula), we're done. (Influenced by this post.)

- For those curious in finding the generators of a given multicative group, reference this post. In short, there is no efficient way (as far as I can tell) to find any or all generators of a given multiplicative group. However, properties such as those derived from Lagrange's Theorem are useful in narrowing computation down to a small collection of powers for each element, as well Euler totient can be used to find the number of generators that exist in a given multiplicative group.
Observation 3. (Prime number $p=2$) Showing that  $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^{*}\cong(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/2^{k-2}\mathbb{Z})$.

Proof. See this post.


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645174/prove-that-aut-mathbb-z-times-mathbb-z-cong-textgl-2-mathbb-z
